# Deduce std::array size?

Tags: c++, c++14

In the following code:

```
template<size_t N>
int b(int q, const std::array<int, N>& types)
{
    int r = q;
    for (int t : types)
    {
        r = r + t;
    }
    return r;
}

int main()
{
    b<2>(9, { 2,3 });
}
```

How can I avoid having to specify 2 in the call to b for N? Why can't this type be automatically deduced? With out it I get the error:

> 'b': no matching overloaded function found 'int b(int,const
>   std::array &)': could not deduce template argument for 'N'

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**C++17 `std::array` class template argument deduction (CTAD)**

Starting with C++17, [this new language feature](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) is [now used by the standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/deduction_guides) and now allows us to omit the template types as well so that the following works:

main.cpp

```
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::array a{1, 2, 3};
}
```

instead of `std::array<int, 3> a{1, 2, 3};`

Tested with:

```
g++ -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.out main.cpp
```

If we set `-std=c++14` instead for example, it fails to compile with:

```
error: missing template arguments before ‘a’
```

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04, GCC 7.5.0.

Comment: Sad we can't omit *only* the size arg. Tried it on MSVC 15.9, and it didn't work.

Comment: Is there something between? deduct the size, but not the type? As I want it to be uint8_t and not an int which would get deduct otherwise, explicit uint8_t literals are tricky/messy as well.

Comment: @AntonKrug I can't find anything easily, let me know if you do :-)

Answer (score 9):

Since C++20 we can use [`std::to_array()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/to_array) for type and size deduction.

In your case:

```
int b(int q, const auto& types)
{
    int r = q;
    for (int t : types)
    {
        r = r + t;
    }
    return r;
}

b(9, std::to_array({2, 3}));
// --- or ---
b(9, std::to_array<int>({2, 3}));
```

Personally I prefer [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) (or [`gsl::span`](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#S-gsl)) in function parameters.

Answer (score 8):

Template argument deduction relies on direct type matching between actual argument and formal argument. The actual argument is an initializer list. It doesn't match the `array` type (at best it could match the internal raw array in a `std::array`, but the language rules don't support that).

Instead you can just use a raw array, to wit:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <array>

template<size_t N>
int b(int q, int const (&types)[N] )
{
    int r = q;
    for (int t : types)
    {
        r = r + t;
    }
    return r;
}

int main()
{
    b( 9, { 2, 3 } );
}
```

Or, if you don't absolutely need `N` at compile time, you can use a `std::initializer_list`.

There are also many other possibly relevant approaches (e.g. variadic template function, or defining an operator to build up a `std::vector`), but it's difficult to say what would suit your undisclosed purpose.

Comment: Ah sorry, my purpose is to pass an array of ints which will be checked against the int mType of a struct, raw array seems good enough for what I'm doing anyway

Answer (score 1):

For deducing `std::array` size you can use generic lambdas (C++14):

```
auto b = [](int q, const auto& types) {
  int r = q;
  for (int t : types)
  {
      r = r + t;
  }
  return r;
};

int main() {
    std::array<int, 2> arr = {{2,3}};
    b(9, arr);
}
```

When `std::make_array`(it's in Library Fundamentals TS) will get implemented by compilers (or you will use [some own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26351623/898435) implementation of it) you won't also need to pass array size when constructing, just use

```
b(9, std::make_array(2,3));
```

Comment: Readers should note that the `auto` here doesn't do anything that an ordinary `template` wouldn't do. This code works because the type of the actual argument is specified as `std::array`, not because of the `auto`. With this answer's `main` the OP's definition of `b` would also work.