# Base class initializer list in for loop

Tags: c++

Anyone have a better/cleaner way to do this?

```
class Base {};
class Derived1 : Base {};
class Derived2 : Base {};

//================================

Derived1 var1, var2;
Derived2 var3, var4;

for (auto* var : std::initializer_list<Base*>{&var1, &var2, &var3, &var4}) {
    ...
}
```

Would like to avoid having to explicitly type the `initializer_list` and, for bonus points, using references and not having to resort to pointers.

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of this loop? What are you doing inside the loop that you need this type of list to iterate through?

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to me. What is the underlying, actual and real problem that this loop is supposed to solve? Perhaps there are other ways to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

The only alternate way, but it's probably not what you are looking for:

```
class Base {};
class Derived1 : public Base {};
class Derived2 : public Base {};

Derived1 var1, var2;
Derived2 var3, var4;

Base* objects[] = { &var1, &var2, &var3, &var4 };

for (auto* var : objects) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot automatically deduce `Base`. Furthermore there isn't even an implicit conversion of `Derived1*` or `Derived2*` to `Base*`, since you're using a private base class.

I'm assuming you actually wanted public base classes in the following code

```
class Base {};
class Derived1 : public Base {};
class Derived2 : public Base {};
```

.

You cannot deduce the common base class of both `Derived1` and `Derived2`, so the type actually needs to be mentioned, if you want to use anything that's iterable, you need to manually specify the type.

However you could create a template function with a parameter pack to either execute a functor for every parameter passed or to create something that is an iterable that returns references to `Base` when dereferencing the iterator.

In the following I show both options, but for simplicity's sake I go with an `std::array` of `std::reference_wrapper<Base>` instead of implementing custom collection that has an iterator returning references to `Base`.

```
template<class F, class...Args>
void ForEach(F&& f, Args&&...args)
{
    ((f(std::forward<Args>(args))), ...);
}

void printType(Derived1 const&)
{
    std::cout << "Derived1\n";
}

void printType(Derived2 const&)
{
    std::cout << "Derived2\n";
}

void printType(Base const&)
{
    std::cout << "Base\n";
}

template<class T, class ...Args>
std::array<std::reference_wrapper<T>, sizeof...(Args)> AsIterable(Args& ...args)
{
    return {args...};
}

int main()
{
    Derived1 var1, var2;
    Derived2 var3, var4;

    std::cout << "generic lambda:\n";

    ForEach([](auto& x)
        {
            printType(x);
        }, var1, var2, var3, var4);


    std::cout << "lambda with typed parameter:\n";

    ForEach([](Base& x)
        {
            printType(x);
        }, var1, var2, var3, var4);

    std::cout << "range-based for loop with reference wrapper array:\n";

    for (auto& var : AsIterable<Base>(var1, var2, var3, var4))
    {
        // note: var has type std::reference_wrapper<Base>&, not Base& as mentioned above
        printType(var);
    }

    std::cout << "pointer values(main):\n"
        << &var1 << '\n'
        << &var2 << '\n'
        << &var3 << '\n'
        << &var4 << '\n'
        ;

    std::cout << "pointer values(lambda):\n";
    ForEach([](Base& x)
        {
            std::cout << &x << '\n';
        }, var1, var2, var3, var4);

    std::cout << "pointer values(range-based for):\n";
    for (auto& var : AsIterable<Base>(var1, var2, var3, var4))
    {
        std::cout << &var.get() << '\n';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use references over pointers (as you specified explicitly in your question),
you can use [**`std::reference_wrapper`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper).

In the example below I also used [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of a raw C array as a container:

```
#include <functional>
#include <array>

class Base { };
class Derived1 : public Base { };
class Derived2 : public Base { };

int main()
{
    Derived1 var1, var2;
    Derived2 var3, var4;

    std::array<std::reference_wrapper<Base>, 4> var_refs = { var1, var2, var3, var4 };
    for (auto & var_ref : var_refs)
    {
        Base& var = var_ref.get();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Without the `std::array` one could use `using BaseList = std::reference_wrapper<Base>;` and `BaseList var_refs[] = { var1, var2, var3, var4 };`.

Comment: @Sebastian true, but I find both similarly elegant.

Comment: What's the point of being this verbose? How is `reference_wrapper` better than a pointer?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I suggeted  it because the OP requested it explicitly: _"using references and not having to resort to pointers"_.

Comment: Is it possible to deduct the number of elements 4 with `std::array` and `using`?

Comment: @Sebastian I think CTAD works only if you omit both type and size (which is not possible here). See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39933567/deduce-stdarray-size.