# Template class and automatic deduction

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction

I've something like that:

```
struct Relay
{
    int pin;
    bool state;
};

template<typename... Relays>
class RelayArray
{
private:
    Relay array[sizeof...(Relays)];
public:
    RelayArray(Relays... relays) : array{relays...}
    {}
};

RelayArray<Relay, Relay, Relay> myRelayArray{{2, true}, {4, false}, {6, true}};
RelayArray myRelayArray2{Relay{2, true}, Relay{4, false}, Relay{6, true}};
```

I'd like to be able to declare myRelayArray without specifying the number of elements, nor each type, something like this:

```
RelayArray myRelayArray{{2, true}, {4, false}, {6, true}};
```

Somehow, I don't get it to write ! The code should be in C++17 (or less) and without initializer_list (not available for avr/arduino c++!).

Thx for your help.

Comment: Some of the suggestions here might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39933567/deduce-stdarray-size

Comment: Do you need templates here? The issue comes from the fact that type can't be deduced from nested brace-lists.

Comment: Unrelated: Use `std::array` instead of c-style arrays.

Comment: @super yes, that's what I found out about the problem. But is there a way to do it differently, like "fixing" the type for example ?

Comment: Yes. If you just have one `Relay` use `std::array` or `std::vector` in the constructor. If it has a common base-class you can use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Relay>>`.

Comment: `RelayArray` shouldn't have variadic type parameters to begin with. Like many mentioned, use a `std::array` and deduce the number of elements or use a `std::vector`.

Comment: `{2, true}` does not have a type. It cannot be used to deduce a type. You need to clarify if you ever have any type different from `Relay` in `RelayArray`, if not there is no need to decude the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **problem** is that `{2, true}` does not have any type. Since you're not allowed to use `initializer_list`, other options are using `std::array`, `std::vector` etc.

If you're not allowed to use `std::array`, you can use old c-style arrays as shown below. It is **trivial** to change this to use `std::array` and is left as an exercise:

```
struct Relay
{
    int pin;
    bool state;
};

template<std::size_t N>
class RelayArray
{
private:
    Relay array[N]; //or std::array<Relay, N>
public:
    RelayArray(const Relay(&ref)[N]) 
    {}
};

RelayArray myRelayArray{{{2, true}, {4, false}, {6, true}}}; //works
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fs5ojonPs)

Comment: Thx a lot for the solution.
I know wanted to make it all constexpr (with "const Relay array[N]" and a constexpr ctor), but somehow, with the variadic version, it works fine, but with the "old-style" arrays, it doesn't :-(

Comment: @Fred You're welcome. You can still make the ctor `constexpr` here, see [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rEn7EG3dc). Though function parameters are not constexpr.