# Class template with multiple parameters and default parameter

Tags: c++, templates, avr-gcc

I've a class template like that:

```cpp
struct Relay
{
    int pin;
    bool state;
};

template<std::size_t N, uint8_t D = 10>
class RelayArray
{
private:
    Relay array[N]; //or std::array<Relay, N>
    EWMA_average< D > ewma_average;
public:
    RelayArray(const Relay(&ref)[N]) 
    {}
};

RelayArray myRelayArray{{{2, true}, {4, false}, {6, true}}};
```

The declaration above "expands" to `RelayArray<3, 10> myRelayArray...`

Now, I'd like to provide 'D' and only 'D'. 'N' should be again deduced from the declaration.
The following works:

```cpp
RelayArray<3, 5> myRelayArray{{{2, true}, {4, false}, {6, true}}};
```

but not this uses `5` for the first argument, not for `D`:

```cpp
RelayArray<5> myRelayArray{{{2, true}, {4, false}, {6, true}}}; // does not work
```

What is a way in C++17 or older to make `RelayArray<5>` choose `D=5` and let `N` be deduced from the initializer?

I've found some solutions with aliases for example, but I'm not satisfied with that.

BTW: I cannot use any STL-containers nor any STL-"stuff"...Not available for avr-gcc :-(

Thx
Fred

Comment: Old question for context: [Template class and automatic deduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78059820/template-class-and-automatic-deduction)

Comment: " I've found some solutions with aliases for example, but I'm not satisfied with that." why not? When you know a solution but you dont like it you should show the solution and explain why you dont like it, otherwise any answer that gets posted might just reiterate the solution you already know

Comment: and please be more precise that "doesnt work". I tried to make the question more clear, please review and edit accordingly. Its also important if you want exactly this `RelayArray<5>` or some other way to choose `D` while deducing `N` would be ok

Comment: What does `D` mean, here? If it's a device code or something like that using a nested struct like `Device<5>::Array myRelayArray{...};` would seem fitting.

Comment: ```D``` is an integer that again is used to define a member of this class. This member-type is also another template. I've added this member in the original post.

Comment: Btw, peek here https://github.com/andysworkshop/avr-stl

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Yes I know this project. But I'm afraid, that won't really solve my "problem" !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to do it this way, defining 2 ctors.

```cpp
public:
    RelayArray(const Relay(&ref)[N]) : array(ref)
    {}
    RelayArray(integral_constant< uint8_t, D > ic, const Relay(&ref)[N]) : array(ref)
    {}
```

Now I can instantiate like that :

```cpp
RelayEngine relays{ { { 3, 1000, 200, 1, 1 } } };
```

which expand to `RelayEngine<1, 10>` or like that :

```cpp
RelayEngine relays{ integral_constant< uint8_t, 15 >{}, { { 3, 1000, 200, 1, 1 } } };
```

which expands to RelayEngine<1, 15>```

So now, I "only" need something to avoid writing `integral_constant< uint8_t, 15 >{}`.

Answer (score 1):

Because default template arguments must be last ones in parameter list, they conflict with deduction, there is really not much that can be done. Either alias or a nested template. Alias template

```
template <std::size_t N>
using RelayArray5 = RelayArray<N, 5>;
```

Can be used as nested type:

```
template <std::uint8_t D = 10> 
struct Def {
       template <std::size_t N> using Array = RelayArray<N, D>;    
};

Def<5>::Array myRelayArray{{{2, true}, {4, false}, {6, true}}};
```

Comment: or swap the order (and provide a default that isnt actually used) `template<uint8_t D = 10,std::size_t N=-1>`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai that doesn't work either !

Comment: @Fred what is the meaning of "doesn't work" ?

Comment: @Fred oh well because you want to make use of CTAD, now I got it